# What is the meaning of the word turnover?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

There is a word turnover which is frequently used in business language What is the exact meaning of it?

Comment: Is there any reason simply looking this up in the dictionary doesn't answer your question? As it stands, this may be closed for being too basic. Look at meanings 2 and 3 [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turnover).

Answer (score 2):

In a business context, it's often used to refer to the "the rate at which employees leave a workforce and are replaced."

So if a company has high turnover, it means that its employees quit their jobs often, causing the company to increase hiring.

Google suggested another definition, "the amount of money taken by a business in a particular period," a.k.a. the gross revenue. I'm more accustomed to the former usage of the word than this one, but context will reveal what the author intended.

Comment: With no qualifier (like "employee turnover"), I'd assume the 2nd definition. I believe the assumption is that most of the revenue is used (turned over) to buy fresh inventory.